# PLSQL : Apply IN operator check conditionally

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, plsql, in-operator

User inputs numbers (1,2,3 etc). My requirement is if the User input number is present in a database table
then only those records should be retrieved. **If User has NOT entered data then ALL the records from the table should be retrieved**.

User input numbers are stored in `table type` and relevant code is below.

`CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE ACCNT_NUMBER_TYPE AS TABLE OF NUMBER;` //ACCNT_NUMBER_TYPE will have values 1,2,3 etc.

Below is my procedure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY pr_retrieve_data as
PROCEDURE FETCH_MYTABLE_DETAILS() is

FOR indx in (select column1,
                    column2
             from   SOMEOTHERTABLE SOT
             WHERE  SOT.ACCNT_NUMBER IN (SELECT * FROM TABLE(L_ACCNT_NUMBER)))
LOOP

...
-- Around 300 lines of code goes here

END LOOP;

end FETCH_MYTABLE_DETAILS;
end pr_retrieve_data;
```

The problem I am facing is, I am not able to write logic for the case where User has not input data. In this 
case I am supposed to retrieve all the records. *But, as per the above FOR loop if the User has not input data
then it will NOT fetch any records.*

I could write another FOR loop by putting condition if User data is `null`. But, there will be repetition of 300 lines of 
code. This will increate maintenace.

*How can I tweek the FOR loop such that if User enters data then only that record is retrieved and when User 
does not enter data then ALL the records are retrieved?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like variable is initialized and filled with nulls. Check if there are any non nulls in `l_accnt_number` and construct loop condition like here:

```
... 
procedure fetch_mytable_details() is
  l_accnt_not_null number(6);
begin
  select count(1) 
    into l_accnt_not_null 
    from table(l_accnt_number) 
    where column_value is not null;

  for indx in (select  column1, column2
                 from  someothertable sot
                 where l_accnt_not_null = 0 
                    or sot.accnt_number in (select * from table(l_accnt_number)))
...
```

Comment: Yes, you guessed right. Variable was initialized and filled with `null`. May be thats why the solution provided by @Gordon did not work.

Answer (score 2):

I think you want `not exists`:

```
select column1, column2
from SOMEOTHERTABLE SOT
where SOT.ACCNT_NUMBER in (select * from TABLE(L_ACCNT_NUMBER)) or
      not exists (select 1 from TABLE(L_ACCNT_NUMBER));
```

This will return all rows in the outer query if the table of inputs has no rows.

Comment: It didn't work. If User does not enter data, then with the above `not exists` condition, I am NOT getting all the records.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you *should*. Gordon's query looks OK to me.

Comment: @Littlefoot @Gordon : I think this solution works if the variable is not having `null` values. Anyways, I have upvoted. The solution provided by @Ponder worked for me.